# Read json and view result in view xamarin

Tags: c#, forms, visual-studio, xamarin

I want to read a json and iterate to show data. But the text does not have style, paint all data together. How can I paint text with style?

```
string a = ""; 
foreach (Messages element in response)
{
    a += "<Label Text=\"" + element + " FontSize=\"Large\" HorizontalOptions=\"Center\" VerticalOptions = \"Center\" x: Name = \"lblRes\"";
}
lblRes.Text = a;
```

Write in view

```
   <Label Text="Hi" FontSize="Large" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions = "Center" x: Name = "lblRes"><Label Text="bye" FontSize="Large" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions = "Center" x: Name = "lblRes">
```

Answer (score 2):

if you want to dynamically build a set of controls, place them in a layout container

```
StackLayout stack = new StackLayout();

foreach (Messages element in response)
{
    Label label = new Label();
    label.Text = element;
    // set Font, LayoutOptions, etc here

    stack.Children.Add(label);
}
```